# Move google map but not the marker like Uber

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am developing an app where I am using Google maps.
I want to have a marker pin to be steady in the centre of screen and if I move the map the pin should not be moved.

When I leave the map, I want the address from the map where the steady marker id kept.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this things

```
mapView.delegate = self;


func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
    let coordinate = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: markerView.center)
    print("latitude " + "\(coordinate.latitude)" + " longitude " + "\(coordinate.longitude)")
}
```

Now you need to add just a imageview on top of your mapview in the center and it will work same as uber.

Remember the height of pin icon should be doubled.

You can use this icon if you need  [image: Pin Image]

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You could add a image layer above the map view, containing the image of the pin pointing to the center of the screen. When the user leaves the map pick the location from the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your marker view on the center in your view.

Add GMSMapview in your top view.

Set Delegate to your map view.

```
GMap.delegate = self; // Add delegate - GMSMapViewDelegate to your viewcontroller
```

To detect if the user dragged the map:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        let coo = GMap.projection.coordinate(for: markerView.center)
        selectedLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coo.latitude, longitude: coo.longitude)
        getAddress() //get address of your selected location
    }
```

Comment: What is GMap here: -
let coo = GMap.projection.coordinate(for: markerView.center)

Comment: GMap is an instance of GMSMapView. replace it with your mapview